# Get number of arguments for a class function

Tags: php, function

Is there a way to detect the number of arguments a function in a class has?

What I want to do is the following.

```
$class = 'foo';
$path = 'path/to/file';
if ( ! file_exists($path)) {
  die();
}

require($path);

if ( ! class_exists($class)) {
  die();
}

$c = new class;

if (num_function_args($class, $function) == count($url_segments)) {
  $c->$function($one, $two, $three);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: not sure. you can however, at your class definition, use something like func_get_arg() [http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php] and according to arguments received, do different things..

Comment: You should consider an alternative design. Could you provide more context to your problem?

Comment: Please clearify whether you want to know the number of arguments passed to a function at runtime, e.g. `fn(1,1,1)` (3 arguments) or the number of arguments given in the signature, e.g. `function fn($a,$b$c=0,$d=0)` (4 arguments, 2 required, 2 optional)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using reflection, but this is really an overhead in your code; and a method can have any number of arguments without their explicitly being defined in the method definition.

```
$classMethod = new ReflectionMethod($class,$method);
$argumentCount = count($classMethod->getParameters());
```

Comment: While reflection methods in most languages tend to cost a larger number of CPU cycles, I'm using this exact method and I don't see any difference in execution time with or without.

Comment: @Cypher After 2 1/2 years of improvement in PHP since this answer was posted, Reflection has improved significantly

Answer (score 6):

To get the number of arguments in a Function or Method signature, you can use

- [ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getNumberOfParameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php) - Gets number of parameters

**Example**

```
$rf = new ReflectionMethod('DateTime', 'diff');
echo $rf->getNumberOfParameters();         // 2
echo $rf->getNumberOfRequiredParameters(); // 1
```

---

To get the number of arguments passed to a function at runtime, you can use

- [`func_num_args`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) — Returns the number of arguments passed to the function

**Example**

```
function fn() {
    return func_num_args();
}
echo fn(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); // 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead, if you pass too many parameters, they will simply be ignored.

Demo

```
class Foo {
   public function bar($arg1, $arg2) {
       echo $arg1 . ', ' . $arg2;
   }
}


$foo = new Foo();

call_user_func_array(array($foo, 'bar'), array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Will output

```
1, 2
```

For dynamic arguments, use [func_get_args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) like this :

```
class Foo {
   public function bar() {
       $args = func_get_args();
       echo implode(', ', $args);
   }
}


$foo = new Foo();

call_user_func_array(array($foo, 'bar'), array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Will output

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: A warning is also thrown, and passing too many arguments using `call_user_func_array` to certain functions (like is_numeric) will actually change the behaviour of that function.

Comment: @BrianHogg of course. Since arguments passed to functions are pushed to the stack, if the stack is full, you'll get weird behaviors. If this ever becomes your case, you problem is not the function's behaviors :) Use a single array arg in that case, for example.

Comment: there was a recent issue with a popular CMS where a validation/filter function was calling `is_numeric` with 3 parameters (the value plus details on the request), but instead of `is_numeric` looking at the first argument and ignoring others it returns NULL and the validation falls through.  Don't think that's a stack overflow (ha ha) issue but rather the other parameters affecting the function's output rather than simply being ignored.