# URL router parsing arguements to controller

Tags: php, url-routing

I know this question will seem primarily opinion based but basically I have a router class.
For the MVC app I'm making, I'm going to allow **3** arguements to be parsed through to the controller. Something like `site.com/controller/action/arg1/arg2/arg3`.

Would it be easier to maintain said code with setting up something like this in the router:

```
if (isset($url[2])) {
    array_push($this->args, $url[2]);
}
if (isset($url[3])) {
    array_push($this->args, $url[3]);
}
if (isset($url[4])) {
    array_push($this->args, $url[4]);
}
```

Creating an array like:

```
Array (
    [0] => arg1,
    [1] => arg2,
    [2] => arg3
)
```

That I pass to the controller like: `controller->action($args)`.

Or set it up like:

```
if (isset($url[2])) {
    $this->arg_1 = $url[2];
}
if (isset($url[3])) {
    $this->arg_2 = $url[3];
}
if (isset($url[4])) {
    $this->arg_4 = $url[4];
}
```

Allowing access like: `controller->action($one, $two, $three)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on which one fits better into the rest of the code you have. Typically frameworks take the last option

```
$controller->action($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

And this can be created using

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $action), $args);
```

https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Another tip to reduce the code would be using array_slice

```
$args = array_slice($url, 2, 3);
```

https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Similar question [Get number of arguments for a class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989190/get-number-of-arguments-for-a-class-function)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, some useful tips there :-)