# How to find number of variables passed in function in php

Tags: php

I want to find how to get number of variables to  be passed in function.

say suppose I have function

```
public function abc($id,$name,$email){
....

}
```

Now there is another function xyz in want to know number of variables that are need to be passed in this function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just of curiosity, why you want to do so ?

Comment: I want to know why people are giving negative marking what is wrong in question

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php - but this may make your code difficult to maintain.  It would be better to use default values for the arguments - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: Many people here downvote very fast as soon as they _think_ they know what is asked and consider that trivial. Many of those downvotes are not really justified. Just don't get mad about it. However you _could_ have found the answer to that question yourself in the php documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get number of arguments for a class function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989190/get-number-of-arguments-for-a-class-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now there is another function xyz in want to know number of variables that are need to be passed in this function.

Use this:

```
$rfunc = new ReflectionFunction('xyz');
echo $rfunc->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
```

But I do not know for what this should be useful...

Comment: There are use cases, for example when creating an API client dynamically.

Comment: @arkascha: Yes, but I do not think this is a good solution. Why not work with objects/arrays?

Comment: That is another question. Obvious answer: because the API already exists? As said; that was just an arbitrary example. Many use cases come into mind.

Answer (score 1):

if you did not know how many number of variables that are need to be passed in calling function, then you can make use default value of parameter concept.

For ex:
// Function call-1

```
abc($a,$b,$c);
```

// Function call -2

```
abc($a,$b,$c,$d);
```

// Function defination goes here

```
function abc($a,$b,$c,$d=0)
{
   /* if you did not pass $d value , $d gets assigned automatically to 0 
      as default value. So in this way, you should not be worried about how 
      many parameters you should pass */
}
```